# ArduinoJSON :: How to determine Array's size in a DOC conatinaing not only Arrays

Tags: json

Parameter file containing MQTT topics as shown below, is read into `StaticJsonDocument<1250> DOC` variable.

Size of some groups may differ between MCU's, for example `sub_topics_win` may contain more topics, if MCU is 8 relay unit. For that I need the flexibility to read a specific topic that can differ in size.

What is the rifht way to do it?

```
{
    "pub_gen_topics": [
        "myHome/Messages",
        "myHome/log",
        "myHome/debug"
    ],
    "pub_topics": [
        "myHome/Cont_A/Avail",
        "myHome/Cont_A/State"
    ],
    "sub_topics": [
        "myHome/Cont_A",
        "myHome/All",
        "myHome/lockdown"
    ],
    "sub_topics_win": [
        "myHome/Windows/gFloor/TwinWindow",
        "myHome/Windows/gFloor/Pergola"
    ],
    "sub_topics_SW": [
        "myHome/Light/int/gFloor/SalAmbient1",
        "myHome/Light/int/gFloor/SalAmbient2",
        "myHome/Light/int/gFloor/Lobby",
        "myHome/Light/int/gFloor/Corridor"
    ],
    "sub_topics_win_g": [
        "myHome/Windows",
        "myHome/Windows/gFloor"
    ],
    "sub_topics_SW_g": [
        "myHome/Light",
        "myHome/Light/int",
        "myHome/Light/int/gFloor/"
    ],
    "ver": 0.1
}
```

Comment: https://arduinojson.org/v6/api/jsonarray/size/

Comment: @Juraj I tried to define `DOC["pub_gen_topics"]`, for example, as an array and using `size()` to get its size, without any luck.

Comment: add some code to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is *How can I read each element of an array when I don't know its size?*, then simply use a for-loop, like so:

```cpp
JsonArray sub_topics_win = doc["sub_topics_win"];

for (const char* topic : pub_gen_topics) {
  Serial.println(topic);
}
```

See also: [JsonArray::begin() / end()](https://arduinojson.org/v6/api/jsonarray/begin_end/), [JsonArray::size()](https://arduinojson.org/v6/api/jsonarray/size/).

Comment: An early try was `JsonArray array = DOC["sub_topic_win"].to<JsonArray>();`. I tried to create it as an Array by adding `.to<JsonArray>()`

Comment: `to<JsonArray>()` creates an empty array, `as<JsonArray>()` casts the value to a `JsonArray`, allowing you to use the for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, your question is *How can I determine the best capacity for a `JsonDocument` when my input varies?*

If that's the case, I recommend that you read [How to determine the capacity of the JsonDocument?](https://arduinojson.org/v6/how-to/determine-the-capacity-of-the-jsondocument). Here is an extract from the section "What if my input varies?":

> If your program must deserialize a JSON document that changes, you must allocate a `JsonDocument` that is large enough for the largest valid input. I insist on the term *valid* because your program doesn't need to support any JSON document, but only the ones relevant to your use case.

Applying this to your problem, you need to put eight topics in each list and pass this document to the [ArduinoJson Assistant](https://arduinojson.org/v6/assistant/), which results in a recommended capacity of 3027 bytes on ESP8266. Now, this is a bit large for a `StaticJsonDocument`, so consider switching to a `DynamicJsonDocument.`

Comment: Sorry for not explaining myself good enough.  Input, as show in my question is considered to be suited in  size of 1250. But there is a real life situation that `"sub_topics_win"` would be consisted of 8 elements and not 2 as shown.
When array size is known (2 in show case) I use a `for` loop of 2 iterations to read that array. And my question is - how can I read an array when is size can vary ?